# Tkinter label text does not update/overwrite

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

self.btn_run = Button(window, text="Run Model", command=self.clicked_run)
self.btn_run.grid(column=2, row=6)
self.lbl_finish = Label(window, text="")
self.lbl_finish.grid(column=2, row=7)


# Submit button for run model
def clicked_run(self):        
    self.lbl_finish.configure(text="")

    if len(train_SKU) == 0 or len(test_SKU) == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('ERROR', 'Train or Test is empty!')
    else:
        train_model() # trains the machine learning model
        self.lbl_finish.configure(text="Finished!")
```

Basically, I have a button "Run Model" which runs my machine learning model. After that is done, I want to have a text that says "Finished!" below the button. When the "Run Model" button is pressed again, I want the "Finished!" text to clear and show up only when the ML model finishes. However, right now, after the first "Finished!" appears, it won't disappear even after the "Run Model" button is pressed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StringVariable and update the window

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

window = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set('')
lbl_finish = tk.Label(window, textvariable=var)
lbl_finish.grid(column=2, row=7)

def clicked_run():
    var.set('')
    window.update()
    sleep(5)
    var.set('Finshed')

btn_run = tk.Button(window, text="Run Model", command=clicked_run)
btn_run.grid(column=2, row=6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```